# jQuery Object not animating from left to right

Tags: jquery

Im trying to make this jquery object move from left to right but its not working and its not throwing any errors either!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var cloud = "<img style='position: absolute;right: 0;bottom: 0;' src='"+ Cloud.one + "'>";
$('html').append(cloud);

console.log(cloud);

$(cloud).animate({
    'right': '200px'
})
});

var Cloud = {
    one: 'images/cloud1.png',
    two: 'images/cloud2.png',
    three: 'images/cloud3.png'
};
```

Im not sure whats happening, its appending to the correct position but its then not moving at all, im hoping to make multiple objects and move them using the animate function

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
var cloud = "<img style='position: absolute;right: 0;bottom: 0;' src='"+ Cloud.one + "'>";
```

with

```
var cloud = $("<img style='position: absolute;right: 0;bottom: 0;' src='"+ Cloud.one + "'>");
```

You can leave the rest as is or change

```
$(cloud).animate
```

to

```
cloud.animate
```

Works either way.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery selector facilities, not an object variable:

```
var cloud = "<img id='asd' style='position: absolute;right: 0;bottom: 0;' src='"+ Cloud.one + "'>";
$('html').append(cloud);

$('img#asd').animate({
    'right': '200px'
})
```

Notice both `<img id="asd"` and `$('img#asd')`
That`s all :)

Comment: Ah i was afraid of this, im evetually going to add multiple so i guess i have to name them dynmically thats all, thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's why you would use jQuery selector facilities )